# Forgot Password functionality

Tags: security, passwords, change-password

I have searched and viewed most of the other questions and answers about implementing forgot password functionality on a website.

However, we have a unique situation. When a user registers and account and uses their company-based email as the main email account, how can implement a forgot password scheme if they no longer work for that company and can't access that account?

We currently send an email with a reset link to their primary email account. Most do not have  secondary account and We do not want them to be able to enter just any email address to send the link to.

Is there an easy scheme whereby we can have the user enter some information and be taken to a page where they can be allowed to change the email address to send the reset link? BTW, we do not want to use/store security questions.

How has this kind of thing been done before? I can't really see any sites that do this because most of them require to send an email to the user's account.

Comment: They have to be able to know something about themselves in order to authenticate, what's the problem with security questions?

Comment: You could go the Google recovery method and have them enter a phone number. Then you text them the reset link or pin to reset the account.

Comment: @Collin - We may require them to enter something we already know about them vs. security questions.

Comment: Depending upon level of required security and complication of your system you can send verification PIN on user's mobile phone.

Comment: @Brandon - Not everyone has text capabilities on their phone. A lot of our customers are over 50.

Comment: This kinda scheme can only be implemented using two principles - something a user have or something a user know. Security questions etc fall in later case.I guess there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I want to know why, there are HUNDREDS of questions EXACTLY like this on So but mine gets marked as OFF-TOPIC. The topic NAZIs need to lighten up or do a better freaking job!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to require an alternate email, or security question(s), or a SMS/cell phone number from the user on signup then you'll be stuck with users that have orphaned accounts.

Here's something you could try, but users will still forget to print it out or not care.

- When a user signs up, give them a one time use "secret token" (basically a serial number)
- - Tell them to print it out and keep it safe
- - Allow them to use the "secret token" to reset their email address
- - Once they verify their new email address, remove the old "secret token" and send them a new one

Comment: Doesn't work for existing customers.

Comment: @MB34 - You can't 100% fix a problem like this 'after the fact'. You could request some information from the user that they did fill out in there account and try to verify them that way. Depending on the amount of information it might be 'good enough/secure enough'.

Comment: We may do something like www.last.fm. They require the users USERNAME to send the password reset link. They allow the user to retrieve their USERNAME on another form using the email address that was used to create the account, we could then determine by the email address on the account that they are indeed a customer and when using the USERNAME on the request link form, we could verify before sending it to the new email address.

Comment: @MB34 - Unless the username is supposed to be a secret it seems like, I'd only need your username and old email address and I'd be able to rest your email/password, perhaps I'm confused about this use case.

Comment: True, however, risk we have to live with as no other solutions available..